Syncing capacity and processing
How can I sync the processing of agents a specific number of agents in a delay block with a dynamically set capacity for this delay block?

The capacity is set by a cyclic daily event. And the size of the capacity is exactly the number of agents that I want to process per day in this delay block.

In order to sync the start of the delay block with the determination of the capacity, I placed a hold block in front of it, which is initially closed and opens with the event, when the prior placed Inventory block is greater than 0. The delay block has a delay time of 1 day.
But it still leads to mismatches between capacity and the number of agents within the delay because especially in the beginning where inventory is not filled sufficiently (i.e. Inventory < demand) this does not work, as the delay block starts processing agents as they arrive in the inventory and not all required agents (demand) at the same time.

If you want to process a max number of agents in a Delay block per day, use the hold block in front of it. Then:

set the Hold block to manual control
create a counter variable of type int
Use a daily event to reset the counter to zero und unblock the Hold block
Add to the counter whenever an agent enters the Delay
upon entering the delay and adding to the counter, check if you are above the daily threshold. If so, block the hold block.

